# Cases of equality in Daykin's theorem

Tags: reference-request, lattice-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of subsets of $\{1, \dots, n\}$, and let $A \wedge B = \{a \cap b : a\in A, b\in B\}$, $A\vee B=\{a\cup b: a\in A, b\in B\}$. Then
$$
 |A \wedge B| |A\vee B| \geq |A||B|,
$$
as was proved by Daykin in 1977. Is it known for which $A,B$ this is an equality?

When $A$ is the product of an up-set in $\{1, \dots, r\}$ with a down-set in $\{r+1,\dots, n\}$ and $B$ is the product of the complement of the first up-set and the complement of the first down-set we have equality. I have not found any examples not on this form.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the paper Towards characterizing equality in correlation inequalities by Ahlswede and Khachatrian, Europ. J. Combinatorics 16 (1995), http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0195-6698(95)90015-2